# How to extend CRA ESLint rules with EXTEND_ESLINT environment variable

Tags: javascript, npm, create-react-app, eslint

Recently Facebook's Create React App (CRA) released a new feature which allows you to extend their base ESLint rules.

> We recognise that in some cases, further customisation is required. It
>   is now possible to extend the base ESLint config by setting the
>   EXTEND_ESLINT environment variable to true.
>   [Setting Up Your Editor](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/setting-up-your-editor/#experimental-extending-the-eslint-config)

Here is the example given but with no detail such as filename or what "shared-config" is.

```
{
    "eslintConfig": {
        "extends": ["react-app", "shared-config"],
        "rules": {
            "additional-rule": "warn"
        },
        "overrides": [
            {
                 "files": ["**/*.ts?(x)"],
                 "rules": {
                     "additional-typescript-only-rule": "warn"
                 }
             }
        ]
    }
}
```

The feature is enabled by added an environment variable.

```
EXTEND_ESLINT=true
```

but on the documentation page it also doesn't give any information how to use it - [Advanced configuation](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/advanced-configuration/)

I've added their example code to my build in a file called `.eslintrc.json` but I get a build error:

"**Error: ESLint configuration in .eslintrc.json is invalid: - Unexpected top-level property "eslintConfig".**"

Has anyone got this working? Does the file need to export a module?

Comment: I'm also curious about this. I'm working on TypeScript project created with Create React App, and I'm trying to figure out how to get rid of `process is not defined` lint error. I can access env variables without any issues, but I just don't want to make a disable lint comment everywhere I access env variables with `process.env`... So I though extending so called "shared config" might help, but couldn't figure out how exactly one can extend it.

Comment: @VladislavKovechenkov you probably need to set `node: true` in the `env` object of your ESLint configuration.

Comment: - **shared-config** is an example there is no module with this name, you can use any module eslint instead of. - if you want to create a shareable configs you can follow these steps https://eslint.org/docs/developer-guide/shareable-configs

Answer (score 14):

While unclear from the [Create-React-App documentation](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/setting-up-your-editor/#experimental-extending-the-eslint-config), the example they give is as if the project's ESLint configuration was inside the `eslintConfig` property of the `package.json` file.

You need to [configure ESLint as described in its documentation](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring). So if you choose the `.eslintrc.json` way, it must be a valid ESLint configuration file, which doesn't have a `eslintConfig` property.

The only things that matter in the example are:

- they're extending from `"react-app"` before any other configuration
- any additional rule is set to `"warn"` to avoid stopping the project from building
- if using TypeScript, place the specific TS related configuration in the `"overrides"` section.

A simple `.eslintrc.js` (notice the extension) configuration file for a CRA project using TypeScript could be as follows:

```js
const defaultRules = [
  'react-app',
  'eslint:recommended',
  // any other plugins or custom configuration you'd like to extend from.
];

module.exports = {
  parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser',
  parserOptions: {
    ecmaVersion: 2017,
    sourceType: 'module',
    ecmaFeatures: {
      jsx: true,
    },
  },
  env: {
    browser: true,
    node: true,
    es6: true,
    jest: true,
  },
  extends: defaultRules,
  rules: {
    'array-callback-return': 'warn',
    'consistent-return': 'warn',
    'default-case': 'warn',
    // etc.
  },
  overrides: [
    {
      files: ['**/*.ts', '**/*.tsx'],
      plugins: ['@typescript-eslint'],
      extends: [
        ...defaultRules,
        'plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended',
        // any other TypeScript specific config (from a plugin, or custom)
      ],
      rules: {
        '@typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any': 'warn',
        '@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars': 'warn',
        '@typescript-eslint/no-unused-expressions': 'warn',
        // etc.
      },
    },
  ],
  settings: {
    react: {
      // React version. "detect" automatically picks the version you have installed.
      version: 'detect',
    },
  },
};
```

Comment: For future reference you can see the ESLint config that the CRA team use @ https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/eslint-config-react-app/index.js