# Unexpected eslint error on Typescript as operator

Tags: reactjs, typescript, eslint

I'm migrating my create-react-app react-scripts from v3 to v4, along with that eslint also got an upgrade to v7. Now when I run lint, I get error on `as` operator in `tsx` file.

package.json

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.3",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.16.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.16.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.1.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.5.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jest": "^26.1.3",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.5.1",
    "eslint-plugin-mdx": "^1.17.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.29.4",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.3.0",
    "mdx-loader": "^3.0.2",
    "prettier": "^1.19.1",
    "typescript": "^3.9.7"
  }
```

.eslintrc

```
    {
  "parser": "babel-eslint",
  "env": {
    "es6": true,
    "browser": true,
    "node": true,
    "jest": true
  },
  "extends": [
    "eslint:recommended",
    "plugin:react/recommended",
    "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended",
    "plugin:jsx-a11y/strict",
    "plugin:prettier/recommended",
    "prettier"
  ],
  "plugins": ["react", "react-hooks", "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin"],
  "settings": {
    "import/resolver": {
      "node": {
        "paths": ["src"],
        "extensions": [".js", ".jsx", ".ts", ".tsx", ".mdx"]
      }
    },
    "react": {
      "createClass": "createReactClass",
      "pragma": "React",
      "version": "detect"
    }
  },
  "rules": {
    "import/prefer-default-export": "off",
    "react/display-name": "off",
    "jsx-a11y/anchor-is-valid": "off",
    "@typescript-eslint/explicit-module-boundary-types": "off",
    "@typescript-eslint/no-empty-function": "off"
  },
  "overrides": [
    {
      "files": ["**/*.tsx"],
      "rules": {
        "react/prop-types": "off"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

[Getting this eslint error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kYLyG.png)
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/78qqA.png)

Thanks in advance :)

**Update**: got the answer in the comments section. Thanks to @certainPerformance

> You might need to switch to parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser', rather than babel-eslint

Comment: Are you sure you're in a `.tsx` file?

Comment: @CertainPerformance Yes its a .tsx file

Comment: @CertainPerformance [link to image](https://imgur.com/a/ILh0LTp)

Comment: You might need to switch to `parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser'`, rather than `babel-eslint`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to extend CRA ESLint rules with EXTEND\_ESLINT environment variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59878948/how-to-extend-cra-eslint-rules-with-extend-eslint-environment-variable)

Comment: @CertainPerformance That solved the issue. Many thanks

Comment: @EmileBergeron nope